# Make headers display chapter title, not book title in tufte-book

Tags: header-footer, tufte

I'm creating an edited volume with the tufte-book `\documentclass`. Each chapter is written by a separate author.

I'm trying to get the header to display the name of each **chapter** and its **author**. At the moment, it is displaying a single author and the title of the book.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you please show as your current settings? Which options are you using for `tufte-book`?

Answer (score 7):

Since `tufte-book` internally loads `fancyhdr`, you can easily define a new page style with headers containing the appropriate information. I also defined a `\chapterauthor` command to be used after each `\chapter` with an author; this command typesets the name of the author and also generates the mark to be used in the headers:

```
\documentclass[nols,nohyper]{tufte-book}

\title{Machiavelli and Pluralism}
\author{Rod Johnson}
\publisher{Interdisciplinary Institute}

\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214, 88, 18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
%\setsansfont{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=Ahrenge}

\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{pifont}

%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{#1\gdef\@chapterauthor{#1}}
\def\@chapterauthor{}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}%
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\quad\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\leftmark}}}% 
\fancyhead[RO]{\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\@chapterauthor}}\quad\thepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Machiavelli and Pluralism}

\ding{96} \chapterauthor{Rod Johnson, BYU}

\section{Introduction}

Machiavelli’s cardinal achievement is his uncovering of an insoluble dilemma, the planting of a permanent question mark in the path of posterity. It stems from his \emph{de facto} recognition that ends equally ultimate, equally sacred, may contradict each other, that entire systems of value may come into collision without possibility of rational arbitration, and that not merely in exceptional circumstances, as a result of abnormality or accident or error—the clash of Antigone and Creon or in the story of Tristan—but (this was surely new) as part of the \href{http://www.google.com}{\textbf{normal human situation}}.\sidenote{Johnson, Rod. \emph{A Machiavellian Pluralism}. New York: NYU P, 2010.}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```